# A concentration inequality derived from Freedman’s inequality

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

Freedman’s inequality is a well-known concentration inequality of martingale difference sequence:

> Let $(Z_t)_{t \leq T}$ be a real-valued martingale difference sequence adapted to filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, and let $\mathbb{E}_t[\cdot] := \mathbb{E}[\cdot | \mathcal
> {F}_{t-1}]$. If $|Z_t| \leq B$ almost surely, then for any $\eta \in (0,1/B)$ it holds with probability as least $1-\delta$,
> $$ \sum_{t=1}^{T} Z_t \leq \eta \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{E}_t[Z_t^2] + \frac{\log \delta^{-1}}{\eta}. $$

When I read the paper [Efficient Active Learning with Abstention](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2022/hash/e5aa7171449b83f8b4eec1623eac9906-Abstract-Conference.html), the authors derive the following result directly from the Freedman's inequality without proof.

> Let $(Z_t)_{t \leq T}$ be a real-valued sequence of random variables  adapted to filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. If $|Z_t| \leq B$ almost surely, then  with probability as least $1-\delta$,
> $$ \sum_{t=1}^{T} Z_t \leq \frac{3}{2} \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{E}_t[Z_t] + 4B\log(2 \delta^{-1}). $$
> and
> $$ \sum_{t=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}_t[ Z_t] \leq 2 \sum_{t=1}^{T}Z_t + 8B\log(2 \delta^{-1}). $$

Since $Z_t$ is no longer a martingale difference sequence in their assumption, I construct a sequence like this
$$X_t=Z_t-\mathbb{E}_t[Z_t].$$
However, I still can't derive this result. Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like these two inequalities are both false.  For instance if $Z_t$ are i.i.d. standard Rademacher variables then we have $B = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}_t[Z_t] = 0$.  The first such inequality then becomes $$ \sum_{t = 1}^T Z_t \leq 4 \log (2/\delta)$$ with probability at least $ 1 - \delta$.  For each fixed $\delta$, the probability this above inequality holds tends to $1/2$ as $T \to \infty$.  So for instance take $\delta = 1/4$ then you obtain a contradiction for all large enough $T$.  The same example is a counterexample to the second inequality as well.

Comment: What if $Z_t$ is a positive sequence ?

Comment: Then you can prove something quite similar to what they were going for (I didn't optimize for constants).  But apply Freedman to $Z_t - \mathbb{E}_t Z_t$ (which is a martingale bounded in absolute value by $B$), bound $\mathrm{Var}_t(Z_t) \leq \mathbb{E}_t Z_t^2 \leq B \mathbb{E}_t Z_t$ and take $\eta$ to be on the order of $1/B$.